# Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin doens't provide my user the cluster admin privilege

Tags: kubernetes, azure-active-directory, rbac, azure-rbac, azure-aks

I have an aks cluster running kubernetes `1.21.2` with those options :

```
Kubernetes RBAC --> enable
AKS-managed AAD --> enable
Local accounts  --> disabled
```

When I run the `az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resource-group> --name <cluster-name> --admin` it fails as expected. So far it's looking good.

I still want someone to be admin, so I give a user following privileges :

```
Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role
Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin
```

I followed the following steps to try out my user is a cluster admin :

- `az login` and input my user's credentials to login
- `az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resource-group> --name <cluster-name>` to download the  `clusterUser_kubeconfig`
- `kubectl get pods -A` to list pods in all namespaces
- it prompts me something like `To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code DKXXXXX8T to authenticate.`
- I login using my user's credential again and allow the k8s application to connect to my user.
- `kubectl get pods -A` fails :
  `Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope`

According to what I have read so far, it should be working as my user is `Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin`. Could someone enlighten me what I've missed or misunderstood ?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, don;t know what's wrong either...